# Base64 encoded image gets cut-off when uploading from android to server

Tags: php, android, android-volley, slim

I have some problems sending a base64-encoded image using a put-volley-request to my server running php/slim.

When I output the data before sending it looks good, but as soon as I get it on my server, the data is corrupt/cut.

My Android-Code for sending the image looks like this:

```
private void updateImage(Bitmap myImage) {
    String tag_string_req = "req_updateimage";

    String updateUrl = String.format(API_DOMAIN + AppConfig.URL_UPDATE_IMAGE);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, updateUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                //do some stuff
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            params.put("image", base64Image);

            System.out.println(params);
            return params;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

On my server, I have a function like:

```
$app->put('/image', function() use ($app){
    $image = $app->request->put('image');
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['image'] = $image;
    echoResponse(200, $response);
});
```

The output in my android-function looks like a correct base64-encoded image.
On my server there is only about 30% of the whole image. Can you help me? Where is my Bug? What is wrong?

Thanks in advance,

RiPr

Comment: Increase post max data size from php.ini

Comment: The image-size is between 40kb and Max 100kb. Default post max data size is about 20M, right? I think this will not solve my Problem.

Comment: your image is change to string i mean in base64 so may be it will cause issue. so try multiplepart for uploading image to server. fast and effective way

Comment: Slit the problem and use CURL or Postman to PUT the data to the server and see if that work. If it does, then the problem with the Android code.

Comment: Is the content encoding same in both ends?

Comment: Everything on the server seems to work as expected. For now (and maybe the best solution solving something like this), I switched using a multipart-upload instead of sending the image in a json. This works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting the correct content type.

in your Java code...

params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Which tells your slim app that the data you are trying to send is in application/json format... which it is not.

Try changing the encoding to match the data structure you are sending.

Comment: Well - why is it not a json format if I put my base64 encoded image in this json as a value for a attr? The JSON looks (in this case) something like
`{
"image": "HERECOMESMYBASE64ENCODEDIMAGEANDSOON"
}`